# When we light the lamp of a room .Where does the darkness go?

Tags: visible-light

I asked my father . He replied : Under the sofa -.-

Comment: Why has it to go anywhere? Darkness is just the absense of light, not a physical entity in itself.

Comment: any law of the conservation of darkness ?

Comment: When you fill a cup with water, where does the empty space go? Or when you turn on music, where does the silence go?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90892/

Answer (score 2):

Darkness is nothing, it is not a physical entity. Darkness is what you have when there are no/very less photons, and thus you can't see anything. When you light a lamp, the photons from the lamp bounce all over the room, and hence the darkness "disappears", so to speak. Absence of light doesn't exist when there is presence of light.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is worth an answer but anyway-

darkness is not a physical entity in itself. It is simply where light isn't. As it is not an entity, it doed not have to go anywhere when you turn on a light, it just seizes to exist as light enters the place where beforehand it wasn't.