# The properties of light photons

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, reflection, absorption

Please consider a closed room with light reflecting walls and in the centre of the room there is a Lighting Bulb. Now if I switch on the bulb, the room is obviously illuminated with light. When I switch off the bulb, since the light photon cannot escape the room, will the room be infinitely illuminated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are photons "consumed"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13500/)

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. Anyhow here I don't use a wooden wall but light reflecting wall.

Comment: in the linked questions the walls are mirrors

Comment: OK. Anyhow can you answer with Yes or No for my question

Comment: Hi Johny, see the link I've suggested - the answer is no. See also [Why do light disappears the moment we switch off the source (inside the wooden box)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90892/why-do-light-disappears-the-moment-we-switch-off-the-source-inside-the-wooden-b).

Comment: @John Rennie, thank you very much for this useful information.